# Regex for "* word"

Tags: java, regex, words

Any Regex masters out there? I need a regular expression in Java that matches:

```
"RANDOMSTUFF SPECIFICWORD"
```

Including the quotation marks.
Thus I need

```
to match the first quote,
RANDOMSTUFF (any number of words with spaces between preceding SPECIFICWORD)
SPECIFICWORD (a specific word which I won't specify here.)
and the ending quote.
```

I **don't** want to match things such as:

```
RANDOMSTUFF SPECIFICWORD
"RANDOMSTUFF NOTTHESPECIFICWORD"
"RANDOMSTUFF SPECIFICWORD MORERANDOMSTUFF"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\".*\sSPECIFICWORD\"`

If you don't want to allow quotes in between, use `\"[^"]*\sSPECIFICWORD\"`

`.` matches any character
`*` says 0 or more of the preceding character (in this case, 0 or more of any characters)
`\s` matches any whitespace character
`SPECIFICWORD` will be treated as a string literal, assuming there are no special characters (escape them if there are)
`\"` matches the quote
`[^"]` means any character except a quote (the `^` is what makes it 'except')

Also, [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) could be useful. Regex's are powerful expressions and are applicable across virtually any language, so it would be a good thing to become comfortable with using them.

EDIT:

As several other posters have pointed out, adding `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end will only match if the entire line matches.

`^` matches the beginning of the line
`$` matches the end of the line

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I would Accept your answer now, but I apparently have to wait 7 more min.

Answer (score 0):

^.*\s+SPECIFICWORD"$

'^' matches 'from the start of the line'
.* matches anything
\s+ matches 'any amount of whitespace, but at least *some*'
SPECIFICWORD" is a string literal
$ means 'this is the end of the line'

Note that ^ and $ are not always 'line'-based; most languages allow you to specify a 'multiline' mode that would cause them to match 'start of the string/end of the string' instead of one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`\"[\w\s]*SPECIFICWORD\"`

Works like this:

`\"`  matches opening quote

`[\w\s]*` matches zero or more of the characters from the following sets:

- `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` (`\w` part)
- `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]` (`\s` part)

`SPECIFICWORD` matches the `SPECIFICWORD`

`\"`  matches closing quote

Comment: This wouldn't allow multiple words, only a single word (of length >=1) followed by 1 or more whitespace characters followed by the specific word. If you change `\w+\s+` to `[\w\s]+`, that would do the trick, though `*` would probably be better than `+` since the op didn't specify there had to be preceding words.

Comment: But the OP does not want the regex to match multiple words.

Comment: "any number of words with spaces between preceding SPECIFICWORD"

Answer (score 0):

Will this string be matched as a line by line basis or will it be found within the text?  If so, you can add anchors to ensure that it matches the string.

```
^(\".*\sSPECIFICWPRD\")$
```

Saying, at the start of the line, look for a double quote followed by zero or more random characters followed by a single whitespace, followed by the specific word, followed by a double quote at the end of the string.

Optionally, there are excellent tools for designing regex patterns and seeing what they match in real time.

Here are a couple of examples:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
http://regex101.com/r/zC3fM1